# How to convert a GeoTIFF from WGS84 to EPSG:3857 with gdalwarp?

Tags: gdal, wgs84, epsg, gdalwarp

I'm trying to convert images with WGS84 projection to EPSG:3857 but warp is not giving me a output I would expect.
This is my command:

```
gdalwarp -s_srs "+proj=merc +datum=WGS84" -t_srs "EPSG:3857" SRTM_1km.tif SRTM_1km_warped.tif
```

If I overlay the warped image on top they looks exactly the same.

This is the gdalinfo of my source image:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: SRTM_1km.tif
Size is 43202, 14402
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (-180.008333333767950,60.008333328098033)
Pixel Size = (0.008333333333000,-0.008333333333000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-180.0083333,  60.0083333) (180d 0'30.00"W, 60d 0'30.00"N)
Lower Left  (-180.0083333, -60.0083333) (180d 0'30.00"W, 60d 0'30.00"S)
Upper Right ( 180.0083333,  60.0083333) (180d 0'30.00"E, 60d 0'30.00"N)
Lower Right ( 180.0083333, -60.0083333) (180d 0'30.00"E, 60d 0'30.00"S)
Center      (  -0.0000000,  -0.0000000) (  0d 0' 0.00"W,  0d 0' 0.00"S)
Band 1 Block=43202x1 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=-32768
  Metadata:
    LAYER_TYPE=athematic
```

Comment: i've deleted the comment and included it as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried specifying -s_srs "EPSG:4326" instead?

Comment: intresting i see 3 different EPSG codes there, could you add info why there is that data there ?3